# Firebase database emulator not starting (other emulators are working)

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-tools

I'm trying to get the database emulator working.

Running `firebase emulators:start --only auth,hosting` works fine an give the following output:

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, hosting
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: dist/spa
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://localhost:4000                │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌────────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator       │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI        │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ Authentication │ localhost:9099 │ http://localhost:4000/auth │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ Hosting        │ localhost:5000 │ n/a                        │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at localhost:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500
```

However, as soon as I include emulation of the database the only thing I get is:

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, database, hosting
i  database: Database Emulator logging to database-debug.log
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
i  database: Stopping Database Emulator
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub

Error: TIMEOUT: Port 9000 on localhost was not active within 60000ms
```

Going to `http://localhost:9000` does give a response from the database so it seems to be running. But it hangs and does not allow the other emulators or the UI to start and will eventually time out.

This is the contents of the **database-debug.log**

```
08:23:16.050 [NamespaceSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
08:23:16.247 [main] INFO com.firebase.server.forge.App$ - Listening at localhost:9000
08:24:14.144 [Thread-0] INFO com.firebase.server.forge.App$ - Attempting graceful shutdown.
08:24:14.156 [NamespaceSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO com.firebase.core.namespace.Terminator$Terminator - 1 actors left to terminate: fake-server
08:24:14.163 [NamespaceSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO com.firebase.core.namespace.NamespaceActor - Stopping namespace actor for fake-server
08:24:14.164 [NamespaceSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO com.firebase.core.namespace.NamespaceActor - Gauges removed for fake-server
08:24:14.170 [Thread-0] INFO com.firebase.server.forge.App$ - Graceful shutdown complete.
```

### Update

I have:

- created a new project using firebase init just to try the emulator and I get the same behaviour.
- configured the database emulator to run on a different port. No avail.
- upgraded java to **openjdk version 18**... (initially I had a very old version of java on my mac)

Answer (score 3):

While running `firebase emulators:start` you might get an output similar to this one

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators: database, hosting
i  database: Database Emulator logging to database-debug.log
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
i  database: Stopping Database Emulator.
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub
```

> Error: TIMEOUT: Port 9000 on localhost was not active within 60000ms

### Steps to fix the error

1. Just go through [Latest versions of Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history), download it from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/). ⬇️
2. Add the `"host": "127.0.0.1"` entry to the `firebase.json` file as shown below in the `emulators` section.
3. Copy the given code and add to `emulators` section.

```json
  "emulators": {
    "database": {
      "port": 9000,
      "host": "127.0.0.1"
    },
```

4. Run `firebase emulators:start` again!
5. Happy Coding ‍
6. [Click here to view the Final Out!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcPUe.png)

Comment: I am writing as of August 2023. I was using JDK 11 LTS and that was not sufficient to run the current emulator suite. As soon as I updated the JDK to Adoptium JDK 17 LTS, it started to work. https://adoptium.net/. No modification to `emulators.database` attribute was needed.